# numpy intalled with pip but not found (in virtualenv)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, amazon-ec2, pip, virtualenv

In an AWS EC2 instance, with Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09 distribution, I have installed numpy, inside my virtualenv where python 3.4 is the default version, with:

```
pip install numpy
```

It installs package numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl without errors.

After that, in python I try to import it:

```
>>> import numpy
```

And I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Moreover, if I run `pip freeze`, numpy does not appear in the list.

Why is numpy not being found? and How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe pip is set to python2 in your virtualenv? You could try `pip3 install numpy` or even `pip34 install numpy`. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. pip3 produces the same result

Comment: You can try running `pip freeze` to see which modules you have installed. Are you sure you're in the correct virtualenv?

Comment: thanks! `pip freeze` shows that numpy is not installed. However, I am sure that I am in the right virtualenv and when I ran pip install, the message said that numpy was succesfully installed

Answer (score -2):

Did you do this:

```
@:source .venv/bin/activate
.....
@:python
....
>>>pip3 install numpy
....
```

This works!